# React final form triggers handleSubmit after the initial render

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I've got only Switch component in my react-final-form. It looks like this:

```
<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  initialValues={initialValues}
  render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="booleanValue" component={Switch} onChange={handleSubmit}/> //triggers when receives value
    </form>
   )
  }
/>
```

I want to trigger handleSubmit only after user changes, not at first render of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Field/>` doesn't have an `onChange` prop like you are attempting. Something like this could work.

```
import { OnChange } from 'react-final-form-listeners'

...

<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  initialValues={initialValues}
  render={({ handleSubmit, form }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="booleanValue" component={Switch}/>
      <OnChange name="booleanValue">
        {(value, previousValue) => {
          form.submit()
        }}
      </OnChange>
    </form>
   )
  }
/>
```

P.S. I hope your `Switch` component knows to get its `value` and `onChange` from the `input` prop.

Hope that helps!